Table Data display - UI Issue in Flutter
I have below static data:
itemDetails = CashDetailsData(data: [
      TransactionData(
        txnType: 'Deposit',
        summaryAcct: 'Account 1',
        memo: 'Salary for August - the long data display task',
        allocationValue: 'Allocated',
        amount: '5000',
        balance: '10000',
      ),
      TransactionData(
        txnType: 'Withdrawal',
        summaryAcct: 'Account 2',
        memo: 'Grocery Shopping',
        allocationValue: 'Not Allocated',
        amount: '-150',
        balance: '9850',
      )
    ]);

and below created Table Widget in Flutter:
if (itemDetails.data != null && itemDetails.data!.isNotEmpty)
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: DataTable(
                    columnSpacing: 0,  // Column spacing of 10
                    dataRowHeight: 60,  // Adjust the height of rows (optional)
                    headingRowHeight: 60,  // Adjust the height of the header row (optional)
                    horizontalMargin: 0,  // Ensure no extra horizontal margin in the table
                    columns: _buildColoredDataColumns([
                      'line_memo'.tr(),
                      'summary_account_'.tr(),
                      'individual_account_'.tr(),
                      'amount'.tr(),
                      'total'.tr(),
                    ]),
                    rows: itemDetails.data!.map((transaction) {
                      return DataRow(
                          cells: _buildDataRowCells(transaction));
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],

below are the helper methods to build the Table UI:
    // Helper function to build colored DataColumn
  List<DataColumn> _buildColoredDataColumns(List<String> titles) {
    return titles.map((title) => buildColoredDataColumn(title)).toList();
  }

  // Helper function to build individual DataColumn with background color
  DataColumn buildColoredDataColumn(String title) {
    return DataColumn(
      label: Container(
        height: 60,  // Ensure the height of the container matches the header row height
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.lightPink,  // Background color for the header cell
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),  // Padding for text but no margin
        alignment: Alignment.center,  // Centering the title text
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: Style.helveticaNeueMediumTextStyle(
            color: AppColors.black000000,  // Text color for better contrast on colored background
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Helper function to build DataRow cells
  List<DataCell> _buildDataRowCells(TransactionData transaction) {
    return [
      DataCell(Center(child: Text(transaction.memo ?? 'N/A',style: Style.helveticaNeueTextStyle(size: 14)))),// Handle long text with ellipsis))),
      DataCell(Center(child: Text(transaction.summaryAcct ?? 'N/A',style: Style.helveticaNeueTextStyle(size: 14)))),
      DataCell(Center(child: Text(transaction.memo ?? 'N/A',style: Style.helveticaNeueTextStyle(size: 14)))),
      DataCell(Center(child: Text(transaction.amount ?? 'N/A',style: Style.helveticaNeueTextStyle(size: 14)))),
      DataCell(Center(child: Text(transaction.balance ?? 'N/A',style: Style.helveticaNeueTextStyle(size: 14)))),
    ];
  }

So The Issue is for the long text data content for the DataCell,
It also make the width of the Column more (increasing column width)
As I have applied color to the Column Title.. If it streaching it looks bad as below:

Below is the normal case..when content or text is small and not much longer.

What is the possible solutions should I follow ?

The Solution is using headingRowColor property as below:
 headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                      (states) {
                    return hexToColor(AppColors.pinkEF1100.toString());
                  },
                ),

where hexToColor is as below:
    Color hexToColor(String hexString) {
    hexString = hexString.replaceAll('#', '');
     if (hexString.length == 6) {
       hexString = 'FF' + hexString; // Add alpha value (FF) if not provided
     }
      return Color(int.parse('0x$hexString')); // Convert hex to color
     }

